# Generating a learning rate schedule for PPOConfig

Tags: ray, rllib

I am using Ray's PPO algorithm, and see in PPOConfig that the training() function accepts a learning rate schedule as lr_schedule:

From the [Docs](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/_modules/ray/rllib/algorithms/ppo/ppo.html):

```
Args:
            lr_schedule: Learning rate schedule. In the format of
                [[timestep, lr-value], [timestep, lr-value], ...]
                Intermediary timesteps will be assigned to interpolated learning rate
                values. A schedule should normally start from timestep 0.
```

Is there a readily accessible function I can use to generate the schedule?  I am using Ray with PyToch, in case that helps.

Ray version: 2.9.3